# Receiving error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I am getting the error `assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

for the following code

```
function RETURN () {
    return {
        a : "name",
        b : 1,
        id : "any"
    }
}
type UpdateInput = {
    a ?: string,
    b ?: number
}
function UPDATE (target : ReturnType<typeof RETURN>, inbound : UpdateInput) {
    const keys = [
        "a",
        "b"
    ] as const
    for (const key of keys) {
        const to = inbound[key];
        if (to !== undefined) {
            target[key] = to
        }
    }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJQKIBUCqyByiAUAlIgN4BQiliATgKZQjVLlWuICGiAXIgERjsAtrV4AaCm0oAjbogCM4yZRgATWb3ZgAnrwmUAvmUNQtAB1qJMpleyi0AkmFMgoiALyk9HRAH4eAZyhqGDAAc0UqGT9EMBBBKVpqIzJQSFgESwAFABEAQXRUAih2alD6WWR6RjB0M1oAHhNzOGAUDGwcAD5RRBCpOHA1HisbO0dnKGIWKggEQMQAa1otf3dEAG0vVg0xLapeKV1WAF0OVdmwQK9gOGoCC-mlrUQWxeX-Kb3KB9coODW%20gMwCp1k9jgBuL69Vr4P6IACEbg8g1owBCtBUnyUbGKpXooOWpw8fyhhlYhn0QA)

Comment: because the result might not be a string and be - never. Consider ensuring it will always be a string or add type | never

Comment: TypeScript knows that `inbound[key]` is _either_ a `string` or a `number`. And while TS knows that `target[key]` must be _either_ a `string` or a `number`, it doesn't know the _relationship_ between the key and the types; so, when trying to assign to `target[key]`, TS tries to find the common type between all the possible types; this is the intersection of the types under those keys (`string & number`). The intersection of `string` and `number` is `never`, hence the error.

Comment: Is the best way to solve this to add an explicit type to the RETURN function (like `function RETURN (): {a:string,b:number,id:string} {`) ?

Comment: @cstoltze No, that will make no difference; TS already knows that (it can infer it). That part is not the issue.

Comment: Please quote the full error message in your question - you have cut the first part off.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes so I'm guessing I can only loop through types that are the same?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it does make things a lot simpler. However, if you are sure that the types will always match, you can use `(target[key] as typeof to) = to` to tell TypeScript that.

Answer (score 0):

See @DarrylNoakes explanation.

Typescript tries to handle both cases in `"a" | "b"` at once and fails. I would suggest handling both cases by hand.

```
function RETURN () {
    return {
        a : "name",
        b : 1,
        id : "any"
    }
}
type UpdateInput = {
    a ?: string,
    b ?: number
}
function UPDATE (target : ReturnType<typeof RETURN>, inbound : UpdateInput) {
    const keys = [
        "a",
        "b"
    ] as const
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (key === "a") {
            const to = inbound[key];
            target[key] = to ?? target[key];
        } else if (key === "b") {
            const to = inbound[key];
            target[key] = to ?? target[key];
        }
    }
}
```